# Reset default permissions for /etc

Tags: 14.04, 13.04, permissions, sudo, etc

I did a silly thing.
I changed the permissions of my /etc folder using

```
sudo chmod -R ugo+rw /etc
```

After that I did some damage control using the command

```
pkexec chmod 755 /etc
```

Then I was able to the sudo commands but every time I use a sudo command a warning comes

```
sudo: /etc/sudoers.d is world writable
```

Is there a way to completely reset default permissions for /etc ?

Comment: Or you can restore your [system backup](http://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc)

Answer (score 0):

Your system is in a very very bad state. Most people would suggest you to either reinstall or to boot into a live CD and then change the permissions of each and every file as it was before.

To get rid of your current error message, you need to change the permission of the `/etc/sudoers.d/` directory to `755` and then changing the permissions of the contents of `/etc/sudoers.d/` to `440`:

```
sudo chmod 755 /etc/sudoers.d/
sudo chmod 440 /etc/sudoers.d/*
```

If you have not already change the permission of `/etc/sudoers` too:

```
sudo chmod 440 /etc/sudoers
```